# Getting DOI from article title

Tags: python, doi

I am trying to create a package that can download the list of articles (conference papers, journals papers, etc.) from a predefined list of article titles. I am able to automate the downloading step using DOI of a paper.

I am stuck in the step of getting the DOI of a paper using the title. How to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link posted in the comments of the question can be used to do this. (https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/how-can-i-get-the-doi-of-a-paper-from-its-title)

Alternatively, one can use the library `habanero` in python. The details are mentioned here: https://pypi.org/project/habanero/ and https://www.crossref.org/blog/python-and-ruby-libraries-for-accessing-the-crossref-api/

Answer (score 2):

```py
from habanero import Crossref

cr = Crossref()

result = cr.works(query = 'An Evaluation of the Biological and Toxicological Properties of Aloe Barbadensis (Miller), Aloe Vera')

print(result['message']['items'][0]['DOI'])
```

---

Just check it out !!!

Try to refer this :
https://pypi.org/project/habanero/